# Compare column values from two tables and show their differences

Tags: mysql

Taking the `id AND net_id` as key and comparing `default_payout` and `conversion_cap` from `old table with new table`

The value `default_payout` and `conversion_cap` just contains the difference between old value and new value.

I have written PHP code for it. I know it is possible by **MYSQL query** but i don't know how query should be for this.

**I want to Compare column values from two tables and show their differences?**

The illustration of two tables and output is shown in below link.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9XNrwM_I66XdlJ3XzhmdFpidDQ

Comment: That's ... um... nice? Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do list.

Comment: whats your php question?

Comment: Its not my to-do list? i prepare image for this question. Learning joins in mysql

Comment: There is no PHP in the question, the question itself is very unclear, I vote for a hold. Please, edit your question with relevant code, verifiable example and desired output.

Comment: I want mysql query instead of PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query returns all rows with difference. By php code read only non zero difference.

```
$extract=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.id, a.net_id, (a.default_payout - b.default_payout) AS payout_diff, (a.conversion_cap - b.conversion_cap) AS cap_diff FROM api_record a, old1_api_record b WHERE a.id = b.id AND a.net_id = b.net_id") or die("No any changes found".mysqli_error($con));

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($extract))
{
    if($row['payout_diff']!=0 || $row['cap_diff']!=0)
    {
        //display result
    }
}
```